# Slideshow in custom-post-type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type **Project**. I would like each project to have their own slideshow of one or many images. Whats the best method here?

Preferable One would maintain each slideshow when editing the project if possible? The other method I guess is to use a slideshow-plugin like meteor and insert each slideshow for each post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try use slideshow plugin to do this. For plugins I suggest you to use [NextGEN Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/). You should also try slideshow plugins from list of [Best of Free Slideshow Plugins For WordPress By Hongkiat](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/free-wordpress-slideshow-gallery-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [LightBox Plus ColorBox](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lightbox-plus/) in the past for an easy way to insert galleries or slideshows without having to edit the other slideshows.